# Matching 404 only with further conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add to the rewrite conditions of a rewrite rule a 404 condition.
For example:

```
 only if (404)
 http://www.MyDomain.com/category_name/item_name.html
 then:
 http://www.MyDomain.com/category_name.html [L,R=301]
```

I manage to do the simple redirection but didn't manage to detect the error condition...
Would really appreciate the assistance of more experienced mod_rewrite users with this.
Thanks,
Yanipan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you're after is to perform a redirect if the requested file doesn't exist (which would normally produce a 404 by the server), then it's actually very simple to do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule $([^/]*)/.+$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

What this is doing is saying, if the requested filename isn't a file, or a directory, then we will rewrite the request to be the first part of the pathname, with `.html` affixed to it.

For example, requesting `http://example.com/some_cat/an_item.html`, if the file `an_item.html` does not exist, this request will be rewritten as: `http://example.com/some_cat.html`.

Note that this will take effect in sub-directories too, so for example, requesting `http://example.com/some_cat/things/an_item.html` will result in the same URI as the above example.

---

The important bit to understand is what causes the `404` error.  The simplest way to understand this is that the request is for a non-existent item, which can be tested for with the `RewriteCond` lines above.

Comment: Just what I needed. Found the -f / -d in the prev search I made but maybe something in my syntax was wrong. Thanks for your help!